# PORT-MAPPED I/O (Parallel Port)

Tags: linux, io, parallel-port

I was reading into linux device drivers and reading and writing from parallel ports. I read something to the effect of

```
ioperm(from, num, turn_on) , where:

from is the first port number to give access to
num the number of consecutive ports to give access to
turn_on is a boolean value.

Example: ioperm(0x300, 5, 1) would give access to ports 0x300 through 0x304 (a total of 5 ports). The last argument is a Boolean value specifying whether to give access to the program to the ports (true (1)) or to remove access (false (0)). You can call ioperm() multiple times to enable multiple non-consecutive ports.
ioperm() can only give access to ports 0x000 through 0x3ff;
```

For the last line in the above paragraph, I am confused about what ports in my pc are mapped to 0x000 or 0x300. As I understand LPT1 is mapped to 0x378 and LPT2 is mapped to 0X278.

Answer (score 1):

None of that tells you what is mapped there, that is simply for allowing access to the ports. If you want to know what is actually mapped there then examine the contents of `/proc/ioports` as root.